# What did the end of "The Menu" (2022) mean?

Tags: the-menu

What was the meaning of the ending of the 2022 film *The Menu*, starring Ralph Fiennes and Anya Taylor-Joy as the leads?

Chef Slowik spends the movie tormenting the guests and at the end, they seem to accept their fate — they throw their credit cards on the table — and before Slowik immolates himself he yells “I love you all” to which some guests say “We love you chef.”

Comment: What, exactly, are you wanting to know? ("What do you think" is kind of ambiguous.) What it symbolized? Why they didn't respond with hysteria? If it was meant to be taken as literal? I'm confused.

Comment: M&TV is not a discussion board. You can at least share your own interpretation, but then you'd still be asking for opinion. The beauty of film (art in general) lies in personal reflection. Take from the film what you want and can.

Answer (score 1):

[Screenrant explains](https://screenrant.com/the-menu-ending-explained/):

> With every course in *The Menu* dripping with meaning, Chef Slowik knew that **his guests’ reputation and pride took precedence over their survival instincts**. *The Menu* ending explained that money talked above all else, and *The Menu*’s guests would rather face death than deal with the consequences of Chef Slowik releasing certain information. Despite the men getting a 45-second head start, they didn't try all that hard to escape, being found easily by Slowik's staff. The women, on the other hand, didn't even try to escape at all. Rather, they went back inside Hawthorne's dining hall and talked among themselves, ultimately accepting their fate.

Comment: Not everything Screenrant writes is the correct interpretation. The guy who found a boat was trying pretty damned hard to escape. One also tried his best to break the restaurant's windows. Also, this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Interesting, I think Chef Slowik mentioned they didn’t try fighting back harder as well.

Comment: The way I see 'not fighting' is more not fighting 'all together'. It's the classic 10 mooks against the hero. They should win at the end, but the first to make a move is sure to die, so no-one makes the first move. Slovik clearly mention that 'some of them' would had survived if they ganged up. But they are the kind of people used to ask other to act for their benefit. Not to act selflessly for benefits of other.